# How to Fix, GET jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 Error 500?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to call data from db using Ajax function in code igniter project. I have multiple div, which shows data according to catagory but when I load page some of div shows keep scrolling only and shows
jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 GET https://(link)/3/ 500.

```
//controller code:
public function get_recent_articles($cr_post_id,$category,$limit,$offset)
{
$recent_post=$this->Post_model->get_recent_articles($cr_post_id,$category,$limit,$offset);
return $this->output
->set_content_type('application/json')
->set_status_header(200)
->set_output(json_encode($recent_post));
}
```

//view:

```
$('#recent_post_cat_2').show(); 
$('#recent_post_cat_2').append('<div id="recent_post_cat_2_preloader" 
class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center" style="vertical-
align:middle;padding:15px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" 
style="font-size:24px"></i></div>');
```

//ajax function:

/* START - get_recent_articles*/

```
  function get_recent_articles(category,div_id,limit)




     {    //prepare url   

   url="<?php echo "/./home-recent-articles-filter-cat/";?>"+category+"/"+limit+"/";           $.ajax({

url: url,

type: 'GET',

dataType: "json",

crossDomain: true,      

success: function(data){

        // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));               

        if(data.status=="success")
        { 



          prepared_posts_data=prepare_cards(category,data.data,3);
            $(div_id+'_preloader').remove();
            $(div_id).append(prepared_posts_data);
            $(div_id).show();                           

            var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
                threshold: 50,
                callback_load: function(e) {
                  // console.log($(e).attr("data-original") + " loaded" );
                }
            }); 
        }
        else{
             console.log("no posts available");                  
        }
    }
```

});
}

Comment: you are passing two parameters to the controller and receiving four

Comment: Your PHP / Apache error log will contain a reason for the 500 response status

Comment: but when i am receiving four parameter it is giving more than 50 error while console